# Using '?' as placeholder withFlask and SQLite3 yields OperationalError.

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

The uncommented code below yields an OperationalError: near"?" while the commented lines works fine. What am I missing here?

```
g.db.execute('INSERT INTO ? (date,value) VALUES (?,?)', \
[session['user'],request.form['date'],request.form['value']] ) 

#g.db.execute('INSERT INTO '+session['user']+' (date,value) VALUES (?,?)', \
#                 [request.form['date'],request.form['value']] )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use placeholders for column or table names. You can try this:

```
user = session['user']
data = request.form['date']
value = request.form['value']
g.db.execute('INSERT INTO {} (date,value) VALUES (?,?)'.format(user), (data, value))
```

Comment: Do you know any reason for this? Thanks :)

Comment: @lithiium Table name doesn't accept placeholder(`?`). You need to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot parameterized table name. You have to use string format/concatenate for that.